# Integrate $\int \:\frac{1}{\sqrt{3-x^4}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

How to integrate : $$\int \:\frac{1}{\sqrt{3-x^4}}dx$$

Please guide what to substitute or any approach as I am not getting any clue on this , thanks .

Comment: This is an *elliptic integral*.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @E.Roi :Your question is now marked "on hold". This means that it will be deleted soon if you don't edit it with more details as requested. Use the button "edit" left below your question. The complementary information that you gave in the comment sections cannot prevent all to be erased. Any complementary information should be added into your question itself.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscatic_elliptic_function

Answer (score 2):

$\int \:\frac{1}{\sqrt{3-x^4}}dx\quad$ is an elliptic integral.

It cannot be written with a finite number of elementary functions. This means that one cannot express it on a closed form without knowing a convenient special function, that is the Elliptic Integral of the first kind.
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticIntegraloftheFirstKind.html

HINT : Change of variable $\quad x=3^{1/4}\sin(t)$

If you are not familiar with special function, you can express the integral on the form of infinite series.

Note : If the question was not concerning an indefinite integral, but a definite integral with some particular specified bounds, it is possible that a closed form exists. But the wording of your question is not detailed and specific enough to provide you further help.

Comment: actually the main question was to integrate $\int \frac{sinx}{\sqrt{3-cos^4x}}dx$ , after substitution $u = cosx \implies \int \frac{sinx}{\sqrt{3-cos^4x}}dx=-\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{3-u^4}}du $  and here where i stuck

Comment: This doesn't change my answer. You should re-edit your question with more information about your problem. What is the background required, what is the context, where the integral comes from, etc. ?

Comment: That's incorrect. $\dfrac{d}{dx}\arcsin\left(\dfrac{x^2}{\sqrt{3}}\right) = \dfrac{2x/\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{3-x^4}}$

Comment: @E.Roi. No, this is wrong. All these kind of attempts are  bound to fail. Don't you understand my main answer ?

Comment: @E.Roi Do you not understand what non-elementary means?